# Java JDBC search field

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Helllo
I have a question regarding Java and JDBC, I got everything up and running. I am creating a searchfield and everything works great but when the search fields are empty I got and I press search nothing happens. What I want to do is make it search for everything when then search fields are empty.

Here is mine current code atm

```
private void searchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    Connection connection = FlatFinder.getConnection();
    Statement selectStmt = null;
    try {
        selectStmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = String.format(
                "SELECT * FROM `flats` WHERE Rent BETWEEN %s AND %s AND No_of_rooms BETWEEN %s AND %s",
                priceField.getText(),
                priceFieldMax.getText(),
                roomField.getText(),
                roomFieldMax.getText()
        );
        ResultSet rs = selectStmt.executeQuery(sql);
        resultList.setListData(new String[0]);
        DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String text = String.format("%s, %d, %s, %s",
                    rs.getString("Location"),
                    rs.getInt("No_of_rooms"),
                    rs.getInt("Rent"),
                    rs.getString("Owner")
            );
            m.addElement(text);
        }
        resultList.setModel(m);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Do you got any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: OK while you're learning, but note that in practice you would NEVER append user input in this fashion since it's a big security issue - cue BobbyTables http://xkcd.com/327/ , and google "Sql Injection".   The proper way would be to use "Prepare" - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when the search field is empty, your SQL statement will be like

```
SELECT * FROM flats WHERE Rent BETWEEN AND AND No_of_rooms BETWEEN AND
```

You can run the statement on SQL server directly to see what is returned.

If you want to return everything, simply query with the statement(so you will have to check the condition)

```
SELECT * FROM flats
```

Update

A very simple example to handle empty fields

```
String statement = "SELECT * FROM flats";
if (priceField.getText() != null) {
    statement = statement.concat("WHERE Rent BETWEEN ").concat(priceField.getText()).concat(" AND");
} else {
    statement = statement.concat("WHERE Rent BETWEEN 0 AND");
}
...
and so on
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I wanna be able to search for specific values also and if nothing is typed in to search for all :) Thanks

Comment: Then you can simply leave out that particular condition. Say if rent is empty, then the SQL will be `SELECT * FROM flats WHERE No_of_rooms BETWEEN someNumber AND someNumber`. Or if the lower bound or upper bound is not provided, just do what amahfouz mentioned, substitute with your lower bound or upper bound value.

Comment: But the problem is I dont know how to write the code for it or what in the code to modify, thanks for answering :D

Comment: Please see the update for a very simple example that handle empty fields. So you will have to handle all the different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to substitute the empty input strings with values that practically represent infinity and negative infinity for the corresponding field.

For instance, for No_of_rooms you would use '0' and something like '1000' and for rent you would use '0' and some really large number.

Comment: I dont really undertstand, how do you mean? :) Thanks

Comment: That is, allow the user to enter empty strings. Then, in your code do something like this:

Answer (score 0):

That is, allow the user to enter empty strings. Then, in your code do something like this:

```
highPrice = priceField.getText()
  If (highPrice == null)
      highPrice = "1000000"

  // then do the same with the low price 
  // bound (setting it to zero if the corresponding 
  // field is null

  // the construct your query with BOTH price limits
  // so you will change your code such that it will
  // ALWAYS include an upper and lower limit
```

Hope that helps.